# Does Google Map offer REST api service?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

What I want to do is to load a map with predefined markers on it. I could write code in map initialization to do this. I wonder if google offer REST api that I call it instead of coding to load the map and its predefined markers?

Comment: just provide array of data in your page for those markers

Comment: Yes, but I still wanna know whether google offer REST to do this. It's cleaner.

Comment: Perhaps you want the static maps api

Comment: but static maps return a pic rather than map...

Comment: What would you expect this REST to do then? Question really doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is! heres a link to their JS api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Read till the bottom, there's a small example.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find any example about REST